# How to control UIDatePickerModeCountDownTimer min components?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uidatepicker

I hove a date picker that i'v set its mode to `UIDatePickerModeCountDownTimer`, how can I set the minutes to jump by 15 min..? so my min scroller will be '15 min' , '30 min' , '45 min' etc.

With property control this..? how can I accomplish this ?

tnx ahead

Answer (score 1):

you can use `minuteInterval` property on your `UIDatePicker` object. it's all in the documentation you know

Comment: i know but since I'm new to this I'm trying to figure out where should i go in the documentation to read about it

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIDatePicker_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIDatePicker/minuteInterval[/link] this is a nice place to start